# Haskell Yesod Running a Handler at a specific Day of Week and at a specific Time

Tags: email, haskell, yesod

I will create a Handler that, when called, it will send HTML reports to my customer emails, I would like to know the cleanest way to schedule it, for instance, Friday at 08:00AM. I can use Linux crontab to call a URL at a specific time, but it will need to be exposed... (Even though I will make it available to myself to send reports whenever I want, at least in the beginning)

Comment: This appears to be off-topic on StackOverflow – _questions asking for resource recommendations, opinion based_ etc.. Even if it weren't, it's pretty unclear what you're asking here. Why do you need a `Handler` for sending emails? That can be done simply in a separate `IO` thread.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I will create a handler just to call it easily and send it, because the Yesod App has the access to the database and I don't know how to call it as a program from the command line, as if I was calling a Handler. If you know how to do it please tell me, it is running with keter

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

```
main = do
    forkIO . forever $ do
        waitUntilFridayAt0800
        sendOutReports
        waitUntilItIsNotFridayAt0800JustToBeSafe
    startYesod
```

Comment: I will try it out soon then I will ask any questions! Thank you!!

Comment: I have an `Web App` running on `Keter`, can I call the App from the command line to achieve it?